# C# Winforms data entry app with dirty/new tracking

Tags: c#, winforms

I've developed a winforms app for data entry and I want to know if there is a better way to handle the dirty/new tracking and committing changes to the database (SQL Server).

My overall strategy is this:
I have several business objects and most of them have a corresponding data entry form.
I have implemented INotifyPropertyChanged on these business objects.

I also created an interface to handle Dirty tracking. It looks like this:

```
public interface IRecord 
{
   bool NewRecord {get;set;}
   bool Dirty {get;set;}
   int SaveRecord();
}
```

Each business object (e.g. Region) that has a corresponding data entry form gets a derived type:

```
public class Region 
{
   public string RegionName {get;set;}
   public string List<Study> Studies {get;set;}
}    

public class RegionRecord: Region, IRecord
{
   
   public bool Dirty {get;set;}
   public bool NewRecord {get;set;}

   int ID { get;set; } // ID is here so it is not in the base class
   public new List<StudyRecord> Studies {get;set;}

   public int SaveRecord()
   {
       if (NewRecord)
           // stored procedure insert, return 1 on error
       else if (Dirty)
           // stored procedure update, return 1 on error
       
       return 0;
   }
}
```

I did this to remove the "database" fields like ID from the basic business objects. I was trying to make a layer between the business object and and object that would interact with the database and I thought the ID wasn't necessary for the business class to have.

As defined above, some business objects have a property that is another List. In this case, a Region can have many Study objects. On the data entry form, I also want to track changes to each of these Study objects (usually via a DataGridView). You can see that I've hidden the base Studies property and replaced it with a List<StudyRecord> version.

Each data entry form uses a Binding Source with a BindingList (e.g. BindingList<RegionRecord>) as its data source. This way I can detect changes to the properties of these objects and then set the Dirty property of each object.

I also build reports with OpenXML wordprocessing and use the base objects to populate these reports. My issue is that the properties that are lists are empty because they are hidden. It feels wrong to keep both the base and derived version of the properties in sync.

I feel like I've painted myself into a corner with this implementation and there must be a better way.

Am I going about this all wrong?

Comment: What you are doing looks to me like implementing an ORM. Is there any reason you're not using EntityFrameworkCore? I think it fullfills your needs perfectly.

Comment: You can use disconnected data (`DataSet`) or entity framework. These components already have functionality built-in

Comment: @jeanluc162 Thanks for your input. I have looked at EF and maybe it is time to just bite the bullet and set it up.